# wordpress mindig theme not displaying website in localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have installed wordpress in my localhost. And imported the content folder and other. The admin panel is ok. But when i open the website, it displayed the below
"MINDIG. THE BEST SOLUTION FOR A MULTIPURPOSE WORDPRESS THEME
[HIGHLIGHT BACKGROUND_COLOR="TRANSPARENT" TEXT_COLOR="#FFFFFF"]CUSTOMER SUPPORT[/HIGHLIGHT] [HIGHLIGHT BACKGROUND_COLOR="TRANSPARENT" TEXT_COLOR="#A4A4A4"]CALL US +900736127[/HIGHLIGHT]
 "
As i am new to wordpress, please anybody help me how to make the site to work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the theme correctly?

Comment: Can you send me the link?